# Best Practice with Garbage collection when application has Global Cache

Tags: java

I am working in application which has a global cache and where we have data publisher also. The problem is this we frequently face the out of memory issue. Now did some tuning but it is not sufficient. We have large no of young generation and tenured generation object. Most of the time app goes to tenured generation and hence it throws OutOfMemoryError.

As we have 2 CPU host we may apply Throughput Collector to avoid pause time but it majorly collects  young generation and hence we are using Concurrent low pause collector.

What is the best possible way tune VM for this application?

How can I increase Minor GC  which in turn will control our tenured generation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should describe what your 'Global Cache' is like. Do you use a library, or is it just a Map. Without any information about its architecture this question could not be answered.

Comment: If your application is using more that its maximum heap size, the only thing which will allow it to use more memory is to increase the maximum heap size.  Changing collector or tuning it will only make very subtle changes to the amount of objects you can store.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: Normally it works fine but problem happen when we have large no of callbacks.

Comment: Perhaps you can reduce the number of callbacks. To avoid this issue, I have a fixed number of callback e.g. one per listener rather than one per event, so the number of callback doesn't grow with load.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: That we can't they are user request and we need real time data.

Comment: I don't know your design, but I am talking about user requests for real time data. e.g. I have written both an equity exchange and HFT system in Java.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea was to use a WeakHashMap, but then I found this article: [WeakHashMap is not a cache](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2008/09/weakhashmap-is-not-cache-understanding.html). See the links in that article maybe you'll also find [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api/org/apache/commons/collections/ReferenceMap.html) suitable.

In my opinion a best practice is to not implement an own cache especially if it is a central and important component. It's better to use a library. Otherwise you will always have to 'tune' your implementation and still new problems are coming over and over. So even if you already have a custom cache in your application, the effort of switching to a solid library could pay out.

Comment: I am looking around tuning the VM with VM performance commands.

Comment: @amicngh: If your cache causes `OutOfMemoryException`s you should rethink your cache instead of 'tuning' the VM. What I mean is even if you give your application a huge amount of memory it can still cause this exception ...just a bit later.

Comment: I agree with you but We can't afford the change in our Global Cache. we bounce our App everyday morning before start of business.

Comment: @amicngh: OK, then try to increase the memory you give the JVM: [JVM Tuning](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/performance/jvm-tuning.xtp)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a cache you need a mechanism to remove stale data from time to time. that's your task and not the vms task.

available cache solutions like http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions/oscache have different strategies how to expire cache entries you can use and extend if necessary.

edit: if (how you indicate in the comment) you can't change the code of the application you can add more memory to the server and adjust the the heap the jvm is allowed to use. this won't solve the problem but it might make it appear less often.

Comment: I added more memory to the server.It reduces the the problem but while many callbacks with more subscription my Tenured Generation goes out of limit and which cause the problem .Minor Collection is happening but not at up to scale so i have to increase minor collection.

Comment: the garbage collector can not release memory for cached objects if it's not removed from the cache by the program itself. tuning garbage collection is just not possible to fix that. if objects live in tenured or wherever doesn't matter. the only thing that counts is heap which can be set with -Xmx512M. your cache seems to just not do what it is supposed to do. give more infos about what cache you are using, maybe it can be configured somehow.